# Singleton in CPP

Tags: c++, oop, singleton, ambiguity

Below is the code for a singleton class

```
class single{
private:
    int i;
    single(int x): i(x){ 

    }
public:
    static single& getInstance(){
        static single s(10);
        return s;
    }

    void incPrint(){
        ++i;
        cout i  " ";
    }
};
```

Now the same code gives two different results for 2 different code

```
single d1 = single::getInstance();
    d1.incPrint();
    d1.incPrint();

    single d2 = single::getInstance();
    d2.incPrint();
    d2.incPrint();
```

This code produces the output:

> 11
>   12
>   11
>   12

Whereas this code

```
    single & d1 = single::getInstance();
    d1.incPrint();
    d1.incPrint();

    single & d2 = single::getInstance();
    d2.incPrint();
    d2.incPrint();
```

produces the result

> 11 12 13 14

where the latter is the desired output. Is this anomaly because of design issues or user coding issues ? How to make sure only the second result is obtained ?

Thanks

Comment: The first one (without declaring your variables as reference types) are copy constructing `single` instances when you call `single::getInstance()`.

Comment: One of the main reasons not to put so much effort into designing a class that can only be instantiated once (and then designing around the assumption that this works) is that it's so hard to get right in C++.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel : I have been working with Java for quite some time. That makes getting a proper design in CPP a hard task !!!

Comment: I don't particularly approve of singletons in Java, either; just that in C++ there's this one additional annoyance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`T x = foo()` makes a copy.

Or behaves "as if" it made a copy.

While `T& x = foo()`, when `foo` returns a `T&` reference, only makes a reference.

---

Make the copy constructor and copy assignment operator private. That will prevent people from making copies all. Making the copy assignment operator private prevents self-copying.

It is not an alternative to return a pointer to the singleton from `getInstance`. That would be a surefire way to let people be unaware of the guarantee that there's always an instance. A pointer indicates that it can be a nullpointer.

The best alternative is, however, to *not use singletons* if you can avoid it. There are many problems with singletons. These problems include lifetime management, thread safety and interaction with tools that detect memory leaks.

Comment: wow!, I did not realize making a destructor private would make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @bsoundra: i just edited that, because making a destructor private would still allow `new`-ing a new instance. sorry about that. i fixed that error at the same time you wrote your comment. :-)

Comment: But 'making a destructor private' also prevented the first case. But you dont recommend it ?

Comment: You only mention technical difficulties, but the real problem of Singletons are the implicit dependencies. That's a design issue.

Comment: @Fred: whatever works. e.g., the dependencies issue pales in comparision with the spaghetti information flow issue. the technical issues i mentioned are, i think, more effective arguments (more well known, easier to understand, not already decided as irrelevant) for the intended audience.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the copy constructor(make it private). 
That will prevent people from making copies.

Another alternative would be to return a pointer to the singleton for getInstance(). That would be a sure-fire way to let people know they have a reference to the singleton.

A third alternative would be to have a copyable wrapper class around the shared data. This wrapper would have a pointer or such to the singleton, and be copyable.

Comment: I did not want to deal with pointer for the very reason Alf mentioned. Making the constructor private worked good

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a reference to the singleton variable properly but it is *what you are assigning it to* that is the problem.

This code:

```
single d1 = single::getInstance();
```

means:

Create a *new variable* of type `single` and copy the returned reference to initialise it. So every time you do this, you are creating a new variable instead of using the singleton variable.

This code:

```
single & d1 = single::getInstance();
```

means:

Create a *new reference* to the same variable as the returned reference. So every time you do this you are getting a reference to the singleton variable, as desired.

To stop yourself (and others) from making this mistake you should make your constructor private.